# Accuracy loss in tin to raster conversion

Tags: raster, dem, tin

I use tin files created from lidar. Because the lidar points are direct measurements of the real world, I believe these tins to be the most accurate models of a surface I have access to. If I were to convert to a raster I believe I would lose accuracy because each cell would be an interpolation of my data and the raster would no longer contain any points that are direct measurements.

ArcGIS online help notes that "Because interpolation of the input TIN surface occurs at regular intervals, some loss of information in the output raster should be expected."

Is this an accurate way of thinking of this? And how much accuracy would I lose? Is there a formula that describes the loss of accuracy that tin to raster conversion produces? Please note I intend to keep the precision the same; ie if I had 1 ppsm lidar data I would use this to make a 1 meter raster.